# 2620:Bad character error in stored procedure teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

Concatenation is working in select statement:

```
SELECT 'HELLO' || 'WORLD';
```

is returning HELLOWORLD, but when I try to use it in stored procedure like below:

```
SET Time_of_Day=TRIM(Hour_of_Day) || ' : ' || TRIM(Minute_of_Hour) || ' : ' || TRIM(Second_of_Minute);
```

where **Hour_of_Day**,**Minute_of_Hour**,**Second_of_Minute** are variables, I also tried without TRIM:

**ERROR**:

```
**CALL FAILED 2620:PROCEDURE_NAME:THE FORMAT OR DATA CONTAINS A BAD CHARACTER**
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting a string to a time in Teradata requires two-digit hour/minute/second:

```
SET Time_of_Day=TRIM(Hour_of_Day (FORMAT '99')) || ' : ' ||
                TRIM(Minute_of_Hour (FORMAT '99')) || ' : ' || 
                TRIM(Second_of_Minute (FORMAT '99'))
```

But this snippet is probably from the SP question you deleted an hour ago (a few seconds before I could post my answer).

There's no need for running 86400 single-row Inserts, simply create all data in a single Select, e.g.:

```
SELECT
   Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY h,m,s),
   Extract(SECOND From t) AS s,
   Extract(MINUTE From t) AS m,
   Extract(HOUR From t) AS h,
   t
FROM
 (
   SELECT Cast(Begin(pd) AS TIME(0)) AS t
   FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
   WHERE calendar_date = Current_Date
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(Cast(Current_Date AS TIMESTAMP(0)), Cast(Current_Date + 1 AS TIMESTAMP(0))) AS pd
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am still getting the bad character error. And I will definitely try to implement using your suggested approach instead of so many inserts, it seems smart.

Comment: even with the use of simple hard coded values instead of Hour_of_Day ,Minute_of_Hour and Second_of_Minute , I am still facing with the same error.

Comment: What's the definition of your target table?

Comment: Time_of_day is varchar with 8 length , when I tried to set value to '124' || ':' || '234' || ':' || '4' , the result is '1242', no colons.

Comment: and even for integer field in my table, I am unable to set value for that integer field with colon like set myintegerfield='12' || ':' || '13', it is returning '1,213', I tried by casting it to varchar but no success, may be I am missing some thing

Comment: @KeenLearner: Again, what is the data type of your target column? Of course there's no colon in an Integer, it's simply a formating character, removed during the Insert. As you want to store info about a time your target column should be defined as `time(0)`. To store it in an `HHMISS` Int you might do `h*10000+m*100+s`

Comment: @KeenLearner: I didn't see your comment about `varchar(8)`. When you insert an Integer into a Varchar it's automatically casted using a format which truncates the string, you must apply an explicit `cast(Time_of_day as varchar(8))`, similar when you use my Select returning a Time.